# Why NSManagedObject instances should never be passed from one thread to another?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I was learning how to work with multiple managed object contexts, and in the midst of the drill

```
let childContext =
NSManagedObjectContext(
concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
childContext.parent = coreDataStack.mainContext

let childEntry =
childContext.object(with: surfJournalEntry.objectID)
as? JournalEntry

detailViewController.journalEntry = childEntry
detailViewController.context = childContext
detailViewController.delegate = self
```

i ran into into these words:

> You must use object(with:) to retrieve the journal entry because
>   managed objects are specific to the context that created them.

And i got stucked, because i can't get why it is strictly forbidden to pass a managed object that you have gotten from one MOC to another. If anyone knows why please could you break it down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data is not thread safe. That's pretty much it.

If you use objects or methods on multiple threads and they're not thread-safe, you're setting up a disaster. Corrupt data and app crashes are common. Worse, they may not occur all the time, or may happen at different times for different users. This is true of any multithreaded code, not just Core Data.

That's not what that message is telling you though. It says that *"... managed objects are specific to the context that created them."* That's a completely different matter.

When you fetch a managed object, you use a managed object context to do it. The context is the link between the managed object and the underlying persistent store file. If you try to use a managed object with some other context, that context doesn't know anything about it. It can't use the object in any way. It's hard to tell where this is happening from your code, but that's what the message means.